# How do I locate reference to DLL\OCX\EXE in .cs files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, reference

I am trying to branch an open source program, that branched from another.. the problem is the branch I'm trying to read from only provide .cs files, with no reference or documents to how they were implemented and with which reference.

VS returns errors saying there are missing directive or assembly reference, but the namespaces used in the program are so vague (Queue, Request, Response, CookieStore) it is impossible to locate the correct reference in Google.

Is there a way to locate the reference in a .cs file? Or maybe, do you recognize the reference in question?

Comment: There is no .csproj file at all?

Comment: How big is the project, would it be practical to show us a distinct list of all the using directives from the source code files? eg `using System; using System.Web;` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do u have precompiled dll by any chance (maybe release build)?  if you do, you can use .NET Reflector to see what's the name of the namespace that it is trying to load. That might help to get closer to finding your External refs.

Most of the projects should have continuous build, so if the refs are messed up, it should be broken.

Comment: I have a precompiled version, and in my angst I tried to add reference to every dll and exe I found in the precompiled version directory, and still no luck (Just more errors :\ )

Is there any free solution alternative to .NET Reflector? (It is an open source project after all, so no budget for me... :] )

Comment: tnx, might have mixed it up with dotTrace! :) enjoy

Comment: The project was broken. some classes were just missing. (Talked to the original developer)